# Dask Distributed produces AttributeError: 'HighLevelGraph' object has no attribute '__dask_distributed_pack__'

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a small development cluster on 3 AWS T2 machines. One machine serves as the client, one as scheduler and finally one as worker. On all of them I performed a `git clone` and manually installed Numpy version `1.21.0` on all 3. However, when following the basic setup, the error bellow is produced when executing A = client.map(square, range(10)) on the Python3(3.8) interpreter. How can this issue be fixed? Seems like an internal error, Dask was acquired with pip install on Client machine.

```
ubuntu@ip-172...:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> client = Client('IPv4Addr:8786')
>>> client
<Client: 'tcp://172...:8786' processes=1 threads=4, memory=8.18 GB>
>>> def square(x):
...     return x ** 2
... 
>>> A = client.map(square, range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/distributed-2021.2.0+19.g2c5d2cf8-py3.8.egg/distributed/client.py", line 1764, in map
    futures = self._graph_to_futures(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/distributed-2021.2.0+19.g2c5d2cf8-py3.8.egg/distributed/client.py", line 2542, in _graph_to_futures
    dsk = dsk.__dask_distributed_pack__(self, keyset)
AttributeError: 'HighLevelGraph' object has no attribute '__dask_distributed_pack__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone having the same issue, a possible fix (the one that worked for us) would be to create a virtual environment where you will install Dask and all its dependencies.

1- Install Dask on newly created venv

2- Produce a requirements specification with `$ pip freeze > ~/requirements.txt`

3- On worker and client machines create a venv and perform a `$ pip install -r requirements.txt`on said env.

This will guarantee identical environments, and hopefully prevent various issues such as the one detailed on the original question.

Comment: Did you find anything else that was causing the problem? I'd like to avoid creating a new venv

Comment: Hello @ps0604, as far as I can tell, the issue was mismatched versions on dependencies. Matthew Rockling whom I think is the creator of the library suggests equal environments on one of his talks. If you don't want to create a venv, you would have to either verify all the dependencies work well together, or  change them on your environment at the possible cost of damaging other projects. I think a venv is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks nazar, how did you implement the connectivity between the application venv and the dask venv?

Comment: Sorry I am not of more help here, as I was just deploying a testing cluster for a project initial RnD. However, I'm not sure if you mean compatibility for a YARN cluster. If so, please refer to this resource from [Dask docs](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/environments.html). In my very simple use case, we needed n machines, so we had n identical venvs (one per machine), created n-1 workers and 1 master.

Comment: This is what solved the problem: I upgraded python to 3.9 from 3.8

Comment: Excellent, glad you found another solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error message. It turned out, that we had a version mismatch between the packages dask and distributed. Somehow distributed got upgraded to 2021.3.0, while dask was still at 2020.12.0. Downgrading distributed to the old version fixed the problem.